# What is the most efficient way of inserting elements to the next empty index in a two dimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a less complicated way (if possible) to insert elements to the next empty vertical index of a two dimensional array, while randomly looping through horizontal indices.

For Example:

Making a table that shows 32 players from 8 teams distributed randomly into 4 rounds. So, we want to put 8 players in each round.

consider the following: `roundsTable[x][y]` is the table, whereas `x` represent the round each player enrolled in, and `y` represent the players within each round. The players will be collected from another two dimensional array `players[t][p]` and they will be collected in index order t(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) p(0,1,2,3). However, they will be stored in `roundsTable[][]` in a random round `x` each time. The question is, how can I put each player in the next empty spot of `y` in each random `x` that been selected.

```
//playersRoundOrder[] is 32 long and contains the random rounds in a range of 1-4. It looks something like that: {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3...} then I shuffle it to become something like this: {4,1,1,3,2,3,4...}. Then, I take the first index of that array and I set it as the round for the first index of player in the first team, then the second index to the second player of the first team...etc 
private void example(int[] playersRoundOrder) { 
    String[][] roundsTable = new String[4][8]; //The table that I will use to store each player based on their round. So, the player whose round is 3, will be stored at roundsTable[3][*Here is where I need the solution. I want to insert each player in round three in the next available spot etc.*]
    int t = 0; //count the index of each team. So, it will only increase when I set a random round for each player in the first team.
    int p = 0; //count the index of each player in t. So, it will increase after each 1 loop, and it returns to zero when t increase.

    for (int i = 0; i < playersRoundOrder.length; i++) {// loop 32 times
        //String players[][] is the other two dimensional array that contains 32 players
        //(8 teams - 4 players for each)
        if ((p + 1) == players[t].length) { //If there is no more players in this team t, go to the next team and start from the index of the first player
            roundsTable[playersRoundOrder[i]] [**PROBLEM**] = players[++t][p = 0];
        } else { //If there is still players on the team, go to the next player
          roundsTable[playersRoundOrder[i]] [**PROBLEM**] = players[t][p++];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you potentially provide a visual of what you are looking for?

Comment: @MarquisBlount I added a visual approximation.

Comment: sorry i should have been more specific i meant a visual of the matrix you are looking to build. What do you mean by "while randomly looping through horizontal indices". im a bit confused on how you are trying to build this matrix. are you trying to store a random number from 0-3 (or 1-4) in each column?

Comment: @MarquisBlount Sorry for the confusion made. I couldn't find a better way to explain this idea. I'll try to change my question to make it a little bit more obvious. Also, regarding your questions, I am trying to store numbers 1-4 which is repeated 8 times inside `playersRoundOrder` array. So, it looks something like that {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2...} then its shuffled to withdrawal random numbers of (1-4) from it.

Comment: i would recommend creating a formatted example matrix in your question. "a picture is worth a thousand words"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have the following holding players' names:

```
String players[8][4];  // first dim team, second dim player number
```

And you want to fill the following with names for all players in each round:

```
String roundsTable[4][8]; // first dim round, second dim participant in round
```

In such a way that

1. each player appears once
2. each team has one player in each round
3. the order the players appear in each round is randomised
4. the team assigned to each place in the round is randomised

Please correct me if I'm wrong. If not then here's a potential solution:

```
String[][] generateRoundsTable(String[][] players) {
    String[][] roundsTable = new String[ROUND_COUNT][TEAM_COUNT];
    List<Integer>[] assignment = new List<>[ROUND_COUNT];
    for (int r = 0; r < ROUND_COUNT; r++) {
        assignment[r] = IntStream.range(0, TEAM_COUNT).collect(Collectors.toList());
       Collections.shuffle(assignment[r]);
    }
    for (int t = 0; t < TEAM_COUNT; t++) {
        List<String> team = Arrays.asList(players[t]);
        Collections.shuffle(team);
        for (int r = 0; r < ROUND_COUNT; r++) {
            roundsTable[r][assignment[r].get(t)] = team.get(r);
        }
    }
    return roundsTable;
}
```

Comment: That is great, I appreciate your answer. But, unfortunately, it is not what I was looking for. I am looking for a way to do the job using only simple Arrays. I'll try to explain my Idea better to avoid confusion (The idea is so simple, but hard to explain without drawing!!).